# ComboBox not displaying items in BindingSource

Tags: winforms, data-binding, combobox, bindingsource

I am binding a ComboBox BindingSource and then adding items to the BindingSource. Unfortunately the items don't seem to added to the ComboBox.Items property. What am I missing in the following code?

```
BindingSource bindingSource;
private List<string> tables;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string newItemText = "item" + tables.Count;
    tables.Add(newItemText);   // comboBox1.Items.Count does not increase
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tables = new List<string>();

    bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    bindingSource.DataSource = tables;

    comboBox1.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List<T>` doesn't support change notifications. If you are not going to modify the list after setting the `DataSource`, `List<T>` is fine, When you need to view your updates to list immediately use `BindingList<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.

```
private BindingList<string> tables = new BindingList<string>();
```

and you don't need `tables = new List<string>();` line in `Form1_Load` method, you can initialize it at the time of declaration itself.

Comment: You itself answered your question, You need to instantiate it `tables = new ObservableCollection<string>()` otherwise it wont work. or use `BindingList<string>`

Comment: OK, but you did say I don't need that line? I can get the BindingList to work but not ObservableCollection, why is that?

Comment: what stops you from doing `tables = new ObservableCollection<string>();` ?

Comment: Nothing it's just that you said "you don't need [that] line" :-)

Comment: I said you don't need that line, but check in my code I instantiated while declaration itself `private BindingList<string> tables = new BindingList<string>();`

Comment: The ObservableCollection<string> is still not working. Is there something else that I need to do differently from BindingList<string> (which works OK)?

Comment: If `BindingList` works use it. I always use `BindingList` in winforms with no problem , I've not used `ObservableCollection` with winforms, so not sure what's wrong with it.